Japanese passport and Philippine passport with different signatures: ok when traveling to another country?
I have a Japanese passport and Philippine passport but they have different signatures. Is that okay when traveling to another country?

Where are you travelling from and to, and which passport(s) are you intending to use?

I’m travelling to the philippines to japan and using my japanese passport

In common law, as far as I understand it, the form of the signature is unimportant; it's perfectly fine to sign differently at different times. I don't know about Japanese or Philippine law, but I suspect very strongly that the matter won't come up provided that the photographs both clearly show you, that both documents report the same date and place of birth, and that any biometric data in either passport (such as fingerprints) matches you.  People sometimes have different names in their different passports because of different laws; having a different signature is that much less significant.

That should be no problem. You either use your Japanese or your Philippine passport but never both at the same time, so no one will look at them side by side.
This being said, I don't know exactly what you mean by "different signatures". If its perfectly normal for two signatures of the same person to look different. On the other hand, if the signatures are from two different persons, that would be passport fraud.

If the Japanese passport has the signature based on the Japanese name and writing and the Philippine passport the signature based on the name in Latin letters the difference is unavoidable.

@Willeke I feel a bit stupid that this hadn't occurred to me earlier -- of course the signatures are different.

There are a few cases where you may end up showing both passports, but I don't think anyone involved would pay any attention to the signature(s).

Are you a dual citizen of the Philippines but not of Japan? (AFAIK, Japan does not allow one to have a dual citizenship as implemented in 2018).
Just wondering why the 2 passports, though, unless you are a dual citizen of the Philippines; and if you are, it's best to enter the Philippines with your Philippine passport, and exit with the same to avail of certain privileges and avoid the hassle of having to present different signatures or supporting documents.
In any case, the Philippine Embassy in Tokyo or Consulate offices in Nagoya or Kobe would be in the best position to clarify or help with your dilemma.

Japan does not recognize dual citizenship, and requires citizens to make a declaration of nationality by the age of 20. However one is not required to actually renounce the other nationality to remain a Japanese national, so dual citizenship exists.
